Not able to inspect layout for API 34. Showing pop up It is taking unusually long time to connect continue waiting in Android Studio Giraffe

In Sdk manager-> sdk tools installed layout inspector image server for API 31-35.
layout Inspector working for Api 32 taking long time to connect but not getting inspect.
Want to find out coordinate values from inspector.
